# geometric brownian motion in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, oop, geometry

I have this class used in order to obtain geometric brownian motion in java and after that I used the values which I have obtained in java , in R, in order to generate the graph and I have a feeling that the formula is not correct due to the fact that my plot looks like this.
The code in java is this:

```
 public GeometricBrowianMotion(double s0, double mu, double sigma, double t, int N) {
        this.s0 = s0;
        this.mu = mu;
        this.sigma = sigma;
        this.t = t;
        this.N = N;
    }

    public double[] simulate(RandomStream rng) {
        double[] answer = new double[N];
        NormalGen ngen = new NormalGen(rng, new NormalDist());
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            answer[i] = s0 * Math.exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma * sigma) * t + sigma * Math.sqrt(t) * ngen.nextDouble());
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

and the plot looks like this [enter image description here][1]

! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFBCc.png

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes , the  problem is that I am not sure if the formula is correct and how should I replace it in order to obtain a realistic geometric brownian motion , because how it is, the price is always the first one , which is sent as a parameter , and I am pretty sure it's not ok. And another problem is that my first price isn't returned

Comment: What do you mean - `price`? And what do you plot - `answer` array?

Comment: The answer array is the array of prices? After that i put that array in a csv file and from R I generate the plot

Answer (score 0):

I thought that your `answer` is array of displacements, moving steps.

And to illustrate brown's motion, it would better to draw positions - as sum of steps

```
X[i] = X0 + Sum{i=0..i} (answer[i])
```

For good picture I'd calculate 2D motion picture like this

[image]

Comment: this is not lecturing hall - do you have any solution for the users question??